# Where to store media resources after app install? C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, audio, media, wav

I figured this would be a lot simpler then it is turning out to be.

I have an app written in C#.Net. The app consumes some media (audio). I have the installer for said app installing the audio in the app folder and everything is great. Except, the app folder is in the programs folders and therefore my app does not have permission to access it.

Where would be a suitable place to store my media after install so that the app can access it with out issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi DanG, welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: One question: Is the idea that the user can also open the folders and browse them directly? And, are they user specific?

Answer (score 1):

Store it in either the **ApplicationData\YourApp** or **LocalApplicationData\YourApp** folders.

You can use the Environment.GetFolderPath() method to obtain the folder path at runtime, as shown in this [Environment.SpecialFolder MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).